# Why this code does not produce output? c++ binary search using xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, search, binary

//Binary search using c++.
The main function does not give any output.
This is simple binary search algorithm implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int BinarySearch(int *a, int x, int n ){
    int left = 0;
    int right = n-1;
    while(left<=right){
        int middle = left + right /2;
        if (x>a[middle]) {
            left = middle +1;
        }
        else if (x<a[middle]){
            right = middle -1;
        }
        else return middle;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    int a[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int x = 3;
    int n = 10;
    int var = BinarySearch(a, x, n);
    cout<<"The search result:"<<endl;
    cout<< var;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What output is it supposed to give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing paranthesis around

```
int middle = left + right / 2;
```

It must be

```
int middle = (left + right) / 2;
```

And you might also want to return

```
return a[middle];    //instead of middle;
```